# Birthdays this week

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-scope, people-search

Currently I'm trying to use the user profile field 'Birthday' to show upcoming birthdays using a search query.

This is the search query:

```
contentclass:spspeople AND Birthday>{today}
```

The search query doesn't show any results, has anyone created a search query before to show upcoming birthdays using the user profiles?

Comment: Is your 'Birthday' property populated in profile? And if so in what format (DateTime/String), I am sure you don't hire tomorrow people. Some privacy laws forbid exposing full datebirth and in most cases it can be saves only as  a DD/MM and you try to query for >DD/MM/YY as this translates to {today}.

Answer (score 0):

Are you under the Local SharePoint Results or are you using Local People Results? Most Search Service Applications have these content sources broken out like this, so if you are running that query on Local SharePoint Results you won't get your people results back since they are stored in the local people results content source. If you set the same query to use Local People Results (assuming your user profile are broken out into it's own content source) instead do you return any results?﻿